# Minimize a part of a post, expand when clicked

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown

Is there a way, or can we get one, to minimize a part of a post to a single line that expands to show the whole content when you click it? Like `<details><summary>...</summary> ... </details>` at GitHub.

I often include benchmarks in my answers. And I usually include the often lengthy benchmark program in the answer, so that others can see exactly what I did and run/modify it themselves. But I find it distracting, especially when the rest of the answer is short, and don't want to push answers below mine further down the page.

Comment: Related: [Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5199/1099857)

Comment: You could wrap your code in a snippet.

Comment: related/duplicate maybe: [How can I add foldable code or text when answering someone’s question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417546/424903). Benchmark results is a good argument for having foldable elements of course, but we can't have nice things. People would abuse it for all kinds of things to hide it out of view.

Comment: @JeanotZubler That can work, however don't use runnable snippets for non-runnable code.

Comment: @JeanotZubler Turns out [I can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK02E.png).

Comment: Years ago, spoilers collapsed nicely, but that feature was removed.

Comment: @PM2Ring That seems particularly silly. Not only because they now waste screen space but also because they now give away how large their content is, which seems to go against their very purpose...